# Which Thread executes the "@override" Method called by an Interface listener in a Separate Thread?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I start a Thread in a Fragment and use an Interface call, to @Override a method in the Fragment starting the thread. This @Override stops a ProgressDialog and changes the Text of a TextView in the Fragment.

When I do the same in an Activity, there is no Problem but now when using a Fragment I got the "only Thread that creates a View can touch it's views" - Error. So I used `getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable)` and posted the code to the MainThread, but why do I need to do this, since it works in a Activity without this? Did I made a mistake?

The Thread

```java
//interface
private ConnectToDevice connectToDevice;

//C-Tor
public Thread_ConnectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device, ConnectToDevice connectToDevice ) {
    this.mBluetoothDevice = device;
    this.connectToDevice = connectToDevice;
  }
//call
connectToDevice.connectionSuccess(false, null);
```

Fragment

```java
//make Thread
 thread_connectToDevice = new Thread_ConnectToDevice(mBluetoothDevice, Fragment_RoutineStartConnection_setPassword.this);
thread_connectToDevice.start();

//CallBack
//Thread Connect Success
  @Override
  public void connectionSuccess(final Boolean bSuccess,final BluetoothSocket mSocket) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        if(bSuccess){
          mProgessDialog.setTitle(R.string.tv_Fragmentsetpassword_Connected_CheckPW);
          if(thread_connectedToDevice != null){
            if(thread_connectedToDevice.isAlive()){
              thread_connectedToDevice.interrupt();
            }
          }
          thread_connectedToDevice = new Thread_ConnectedToDevice(mSocket, sTryingDonglePassword);
          thread_connectedToDevice.start();

        }else{
          mProgessDialog.dismiss();
          tv_Fragmentsetpassword_userhint
              .setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Mercedes_RED, null));
          tv_Fragmentsetpassword_userhint.setText(R.string.tv_Fragmentsetpassword_ConnectionFailed);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I have the feeling that I passed the wrong listener Instance to the Thread.

As asked this is the callback realized the same way but in a Activity:
Thread

```java
//listener
private Finished_AskingForInformation listener;

//C-Tor
public Td_AskForInformation(
      Finished_AskingForInformation listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

//call
listener.AskingFinished();
```

Activity

```java
//Create and start thread
td_askForInformation = new Td_AskForInformation(this);
    td_askForInformation.start();

//CallBack
@Override
  public void AskingFinished() {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
  }
```

Comment: How are you doing it in the activity? Can you include that code as well?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad added.